# Difference between Movie including a Review & vice versa

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, schema.org, json-ld

I'm just wondering, if there is a difference in SEO between a `Movie` object including a `Review` object and vice versa, when using Schema.org on a webpage.

For clarification, see these abstract examples.
You can include a `Movie` object into a `Review` object (stripped down to necessary contents):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"Review",
  "itemReviewed":{
    "@type":"Movie",
    "name":"Gravity",
    "director":{
     ...
    },
    "actor":[
    ...
    ]
  },
  "reviewRating":{
    "@type":"Rating",
    "worstRating":1,
    "bestRating":4,
    "ratingValue":3.5
  }
}
</script>
```

or you can include a `Review` object into a `Movie` object

```html
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Movie",
        "name": "Gravity",
        "director": [...],
        "actor": [...],
        "description": "...",
        "review": [{
        "@type": "Review",
            "author": {
            "..."
            },
           "description": "...",
            "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "10",
                "ratingValue": "8",
                "worstRating": "0"
            }
            }
            ]
        }
</script>
```

Is there a difference in the interpretation of Google on the result pages, asumed the Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't throw any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, it should not make a difference. While `itemReviewed` and `review` are not inverse properties (because `itemReviewed` can also be used for ratings, not only reviews), they mean essentially the same thing in your examples.

However, it’s conceivable that a consumer would only support (or: look for) one of the properties, e.g., because the other one is newer (and they did not update yet), or because they only look for specific types, or because they are just bad, etc.

Google, in particular, explicitly claims to support both variants for their [Review Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#reviews), as they say about their interpretation of the `itemReviewed` property:

> The item that is being reviewed. This needs to be a valid schema.org type. *** If review is embedded into another schema.org type, using [`review`](http://schema.org/review) property, then there is no need to mark up the itemReviewed property.**